# How do I access the desk and conference room computers in the lab?

Tags: assassins-creed

I've just reached the end of the original Assassins Creed, and I've presumably missed something I was supposed to do over the course of the game, because while I'm able to access the terminal connected to the Animus (and so read Lucy's emails), I'm unable to access either the machine on the desk in the main room, or the one on the conference room table.

So, what should I have done, and when, to gain access to these machines?
And given I've now completed the game, is there a way to now unlock them?

*PS: I know I can look up the computers' contents on the web, and have done so, it's just annoying that I'd somehow missed what feels like it should have be a part of the game's experience.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had to pick-pocket Warren's pocket when he stands over by the window to get his pen to access his computer, then read his emails to get the password to the conference room computer. He stands over there a lot, but I missed it too, so don't feel bad.

If you're already at the end, and he's already left for the last time though, then I'm afraid that there's nothing that you can do short of just starting a new game on the main menu.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. I don't recall that being signposted during the game at all, but oh well. Thanks :)

Comment: It was very subtle.  When you find Lucy's pen, one of the emails on her computer tells Warren "Stop leaving your pen hanging out of your pocket, it's a security risk."  That was the only clue I got.